# What is the coefficient of $(z-\pi)^2$ in Taylor series expansion of $\sin (z)/ (z-\pi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to determine the coefficient of $(z- \pi)^2$ in Taylor series expansion of $f(z)=\sin (z)/ (z-\pi)$ if $z \neq \pi $, $-1$ if $z=\pi$ around $\pi$.

How can this be done? I don't know how to do apply Taylor theorem here.

Comment: @MattSamuel I had not seen your comment. I mainly meant to clean up the post.// Ramdev: please provide some details about what you know about the problem.

Comment: find the coefficient of (z−π)^2.

Comment: i dont know how to do apply taylor theorem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start

> $$ f(z)=\frac{\sin (z)}{z-\pi} = \frac{\sin( (z-\pi)+\pi )}{z-\pi}. $$

Now use the identity

> $$ \sin( a+b )= \sin s \cos b + \sin b \cos a $$

and the power series of $\sin(t)$ to finish the problem.

Comment: thanks. but can we solve this problem in any another approach

Comment: i solve it and got the answer 1/6

Comment: @Ramdev: I gave you this approach because it depends on using the Laurent series of $f(z)$ which what they usually teach!

Comment: @Ramdev: Yes, it is correct! Good job!

Answer (score 3):

It will be the same as the coefficient of $(z-\pi)^3$ in the Taylor series expansion of $f(z) = \sin(z)$ around $z = \pi$.  This is just $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\pi)/3!$.